# Karma error: unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

We are trying to test our controller with Karma, but Karma keeps complaining about an unknown provider:

> Error: `[$injector:unpr]` Unknown provider: `userProvider` <- `user`

Are we injecting the `user` correctly?

Our code:

**controller-test.js:**

```
describe('Controller', function () {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var ctrl, scope, user;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _user_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('controller', {
            $scope: scope
        });
        user = _user_;
    })); 

    it("should have scope defined", function () {
        expect(scope).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**app.js:**

```
(function () {
    var myApplication = angular.module("myApp", [
        "angucomplete-alt"            
    ]);

    fetchData().then(bootstrapApplication);

    function fetchData() {
        var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
        var $http = initInjector.get("$http");

        // Get user info before app is loaded
        return $http.get('/api/user').then(function (response) {
            myApplication.value("user", response.data);
        }, function (errorResponse) {
            // Handle error case
            console.error("Obtaining user information failed when bootstrapping Angular app");
        });
    }

    function bootstrapApplication() {
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]);
        });
    }
})();
```

**controller.js:**

```
angular.module("myApp")
.controller("controller", ["$scope", "user", "$window",
    function ($scope, user, $window) { ... }]);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing your controller, you should do so in isolation. I would simply put a mocked `user` object into the *locals* hashmap (along with `$scope`), eg

```
describe('Controller', function() {
    var ctrl, scope, user, $window;

    beforeEach(function() {
        user = {
            id: 'fake_id',
            username: 'fake_username'
        };
        $window = jasmine.createSpyObj('$window', ['some', 'methods']);

        module('myApp');

        inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('controller', {
                $scope: scope,
                user: user,
                $window: $window
            });
        });
    });
});
```

An example spec might be to test that the injected `user` object is placed onto the scope. Eg

```
it('puts the user onto the controller scope', function() {
    expect(scope.user).toBe(user);
});
```

---

In unit tests with `ngMock` in place (which I assume you have), all `$http` calls go through a mocked backend (`$httpBackend`) that does not perform real HTTP calls unless specifically configured to do so.

Even if your `fetchData` function were to run when testing (which I suspect it is not doing else you'd get some console errors), it wouldn't retrieve any data anyway.